# tcl : pass columnName dynamically to SQL update query

Tags: oracle, tcl, dynamic-sql

I am trying to pass the columnName to a tcl sql update query. I am aware I can pass dynamic values of columns with [list :substitutedParam $itsValue] format where I have already set the value of variable `itsValue` but I am not able to make it work with update. here is what I am trying :

```
set returncode [catch { SQL "UPDATE schemaName.TableName SET :columnName='u' WHERE key=$keyValue" [list columnName $attr ]} result]
```

In above, only solution I am looking for is: Is at all possible to pass columnName when and what I prefer so I can use the same sql query to update multiple columns (not simultaneously offcourse).

```
tcl version :8.4
database: Oracle 18c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, but I think you can only use parameters with **value** parts of the query

```
set returncode [catch {
    SQL "UPDATE schemaName.TableName SET $attr='u' WHERE key=:key" [list key $keyValue]
} result]
```

Comment: Thanks. Somehow we can still replace the name of the table but not column names.  set col1Value "myColValue"
set tabName "myTab"
SQL "UPDATE schemaName.$tabName SET col2='u' WHERE col1=$col1Value"